# in SQL Loader, Can Caret (^) be used as delimiter?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using Oracle SQL Loader to load some data into database from a plain text file. Due to lots of special characters are contained in the data so we have to use caret ^ as the delimiter.

Just wondering whether SQL loader allows that to happen?

Thanks heaps in advance

Comment: Yes, you can use `^` (Carert) as a delimiter. There is no restriction against using ^

Comment: Hi Incognito, Thanks a lot for your help